# Vim crash with :py3 import sys; print(sys.version)

Tags: gvim, microsoft-windows, vimscript-python

- Windows 8
- Vim 8.0.584, 32 bit from https://tuxproject.de/projects/vim/ .7z archives: x86
- python36.dll, 32 bit from https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.0/python-3.6.0-embed-win32.zip
- copied python36.dll in the directory where vim.exe and gvim.exe are located
- starting gvim and then testing the python support with :py3 import sys; print(sys.version) gvim crashes without any further information.
- starting vim and then testing the python support with :py3 import sys; print(sys.version) vim crashes. I can read Fatal python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec followed by some unicode chars...

Any idea how to fix the problem?

Update [ 2017-04-25 - 17:46:07 ]
also tested with python36.dll from:

- python-3.6.1-embed-win32.zip
- python-3.6.0b4-embed-win32.zip
- python-3.6.0b3-embed-win32.zip
- python-3.6.0b2-embed-win32.zip
- python-3.6.0b1-embed-win32.zip
- python-3.6.0a4-embed-win32.zip
- python-3.6.0a3-embed-win32.zip
- python-3.6.0a2-embed-win32.zip
- python-3.6.0a1-embed-win32.zip

Version output from gvim gathered with

```
:redir @a
:version
:redir END
```

and finally pasted with CTRl+r a into my document.

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Apr 23 2017 18:46:39)
MS-Windows 32 Bit GUI Version mit OLE-Unterstützung
Inklusive der Korrekturen: 1-584
Übersetzt von hp@HP-PC
Riesige Version mit GUI. Ein- (+) oder ausschließlich (-) der Eigenschaften:
+acl                +digraphs           +langmap            -postscript         -termresponse
+arabic             +directx            +libcall            +printer            +textobjects
+autocmd            -dnd                +linebreak          +profile            +timers
+balloon_eval       -ebcdic             +lispindent         +python/dyn         +title
+browse             +emacs_tags         +listcmds           +python3/dyn        +toolbar
++builtin_terms     +eval               +localmap           +quickfix           +user_commands
+byte_offset        +ex_extra           +lua/dyn            +reltime            +vertsplit
+channel            +extra_search       +menu               +rightleft          +virtualedit
+cindent            +farsi              +mksession          +ruby/dyn           +visual
+clientserver       +file_in_path       +modify_fname       +scrollbind         +visualextra
+clipboard          +find_in_path       +mouse              +signs              +viminfo
+cmdline_compl      +float              +mouseshape         +smartindent        +vreplace
+cmdline_hist       +folding            +multi_byte_ime/dyn +startuptime        +wildignore
+cmdline_info       -footer             +multi_lang         +statusline         +wildmenu
+comments           +gettext/dyn        +mzscheme/dyn       -sun_workshop       +windows
+conceal            -hangul_input       +netbeans_intg      +syntax             +writebackup
+cryptv             +iconv/dyn          +num64              +tag_binary         -xfontset
+cscope             +insert_expand      +ole                +tag_old_static     -xim
+cursorbind         +job                +packages           -tag_any_white      +xpm_w32
+cursorshape        +jumplist           +path_extra         +tcl/dyn            -xterm_save
+dialog_con_gui     +keymap             +perl/dyn           -termguicolors      
+diff               +lambda             +persistent_undo    -tgetent            
          System-vimrc-Datei: "$VIM\vimrc"
        Benutzer-vimrc-Datei: "$HOME\_vimrc"
 zweite Benutzer-vimrc-Datei: "$HOME\vimfiles\vimrc"
 dritte Benutzer-vimrc-Datei: "$VIM\_vimrc"
         Benutzer-exrc-Datei: "$HOME\_exrc"
 zweite Benutzer-exrc-Datei: "$VIM\_exrc"
         System-gvimrc-Datei: "$VIM\gvimrc"
       Benutzer-gvimrc-Datei: "$HOME\_gvimrc"
zweite Benutzer-gvimrc-Datei: "$HOME\vimfiles\gvimrc"
dritte Benutzer-gvimrc-Datei: "$VIM\_gvimrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME\defaults.vim"
           System-Menü-Datei: "$VIMRUNTIME\menu.vim"
Übersetzt: cl -c /W3 /nologo  -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_PATHDEF -DWIN32  -DFEAT_CSCOPE -DFEAT_NETBEANS_INTG -DFEAT_JOB_CHANNEL   -DFEAT_XPM_W32   -DWINVER=0x0501 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501  /Fo.\ObjGXOULYHTRZi386/ /MP -DHAVE_STDINT_H /Ox /GL -DNDEBUG  /MD -DFEAT_OLE -DFEAT_MBYTE_IME -DDYNAMIC_IME -DGLOBAL_IME -DFEAT_MBYTE -DFEAT_GUI_W32 -DFEAT_DIRECTX -DDYNAMIC_DIRECTX -DDYNAMIC_ICONV -DDYNAMIC_GETTEXT -DFEAT_TCL -DDYNAMIC_TCL -DDYNAMIC_TCL_DLL=\"tcl86.dll\" -DDYNAMIC_TCL_VER=\"8.6\" -DFEAT_LUA -DDYNAMIC_LUA -DDYNAMIC_LUA_DLL=\"lua53.dll\" -DFEAT_PYTHON -DDYNAMIC_PYTHON -DDYNAMIC_PYTHON_DLL=\"python27.dll\" -DFEAT_PYTHON3 -DDYNAMIC_PYTHON3 -DDYNAMIC_PYTHON3_DLL=\"python36.dll\" -DFEAT_MZSCHEME -I "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\racket-x86\include" -DDYNAMIC_MZSCHEME -DDYNAMIC_MZSCH_DLL=\"libracketxxxxxxx.dll\" -DDYNAMIC_MZGC_DLL=\"libmzgcxxxxxxx.dll\" -DFEAT_PERL -DPERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT -DPERL_IMPLICIT_SYS -DDYNAMIC_PERL -DDYNAMIC_PERL_DLL=\"perl524.dll\" -DFEAT_RUBY -DDYNAMIC_RUBY -DDYNAMIC_RUBY_VER=24 -DDYNAMIC_RUBY_DLL=\"msvcrt-ruby240.dll\" -DFEAT_HUGE /Fd.\ObjGXOULYHTRZi386/ /Zi
Linken: link /RELEASE /nologo /subsystem:windows /LTCG:STATUS oldnames.lib kernel32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib gdi32.lib  comdlg32.lib ole32.lib uuid.lib /machine:i386 gdi32.lib version.lib   winspool.lib comctl32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib  /machine:i386  msvcrt.lib oleaut32.lib user32.lib  /nodefaultlib:lua53.lib  /STACK:8388608  /nodefaultlib:python27.lib /nodefaultlib:python36.lib   "C:\TCL_x86\lib\tclstub86.lib" WSock32.lib .\xpm\x86\lib-vc14\libXpm.lib /PDB:gvim.pdb -debug
```

Comment: Is `/path/to/python.dll` included in your `$PATH` environment variable? (it needs to be just the directory if I'm correct)

Comment: The python.dll is in the same directory as vim.exe and gvim.exe. The path of vim.exe and gvim.exe is set in $path.

Comment: Did you read this :help python-2-and-3? Try to start vim wo configuration and plugins and then :py3 import sys; print(sys.version)

Comment: I tried gvim -u NONE with the same result. I've read the help entry and options +python/dyn +python3/dyn are set, so Python 2 and 3 should be supported. Python 2 (python27.dll) works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved.
The trouble was caused by one or both copied pythonxx.dll's.

Usally I work with my installed Anaconda Python (currently Python 3.5.2) environment.
No separate Python 2 or Python 3 installations exist.
As mentioned in one of my comments `gvim -u NONE` results also in an crash of gvim.

How to fix it:
I installed python-2.7.13.msi and python-3.6.1.msi both 32-bit corresponding to my vim/gvim 32-bit package.
Copied python27.dll and python36.dll from the installation folders to my vim/gvim install directory where the *.exe's are located.
Afterwards I uninstalled both msi packages to avoid getting confused with Anaconda installation.

Now everything works fine.