# No python support

Tags: microsoft-windows, vimscript-python

I recently started out with gVim 8 for windows and i noticed that the higher end plugins that provide more functionality require python support or something like that. But for some reason i am not able to make them work , for example i have recently installed MuComplete but when i try using it on a python file i am told : "Sorry , this command is disabled , the Python's site module could not be loaded".

My vim version was compiled with +python and +python3 and i have tried installing only python 3 , then only python 2 and now i have both. I tried playing around trying to set the PythonThreedDll and the PythonDll options according to my python version , adding the folders to path and since i could not find the python27.dll i downloaded one of the internet and it still didn't work.

How can i fix that ?

Comment: Have you tried answer from this https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/12231/vim-crash-with-py3-import-sys-printsys-version question?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using CMD or Power shell?  if you are using command prompt first switch to power shell and see if the problem is solved or not.

If not check your .vim or \vim in windows directory if you can find vimrc or .vimrc files if both are there delete vimrc and keep .vimrc.

Last but not the least read this [blog](https://realpython.com/blog/python/vim-and-python-a-match-made-in-heaven/) for setting up vim for python.just change . with \ as windows directory structure is different.